# Wordpress custom database table not recognized

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've manually created a custom table, `sdp_invites`, for my wordpress (v3.4.2) site. I've done this many times in the past, but now I'm unable to use any of the `$wpdb` methods:

```
global $wpdb;
global $current_user;

$query = "INSERT INTO spd_invites (sender_id,receiver_id,job_id,job_title,job_slug,employer_id) VALUES ('{$current_user->ID}','{$resume->user_id}','{$job_id}','{$job_title}','{$job_slug}','{$employer_id}')";

$wpdb->get_results($query); //ERROR...
$wpdb->query($query); //ERROR...
```

Here's the error:

```
WordPress database error: [Table 'sow2.spd_invites' doesn't exist]
INSERT INTO spd_invites (sender_id,receiver_id,job_id,job_title,job_slug,employer_id) VALUES ('799','809','6','Professional Basket Weaver','professional-basket-weaver','5')
```

I know the table exists because I manually created it and I can see it in phpMyAdmin. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

UPDATE:
The WP user is called "root" (on my local dev setup). Here's the privileges listed in phpMyAdmin:

```
User    Host             Type    Privileges  Grant  Action
root    localhost    global  ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes
```

UPDATE2:
Just to rule out a bunch of possibilities, I tried a simpler query: `"SELECT * FROM sdp_invites"`. This throws the same error. When I change to a wp core table, it works without error `"SELECT * FROM sdp_invites"`

Comment: Is the correct database selected?

Comment: Does doing just a select of that table throw the same error?

Comment: Yes. sow2 is the correct DB. And everything else on the site is working.

Comment: This should certainly work if you have the proper schema selected - are wordpress and your custom table in the same schema?

Comment: is spd the same prefix as all the wp tables?

Comment: Did you create the table with the same user as Wordpress is logging in as?

Comment: @MrD Yes. Same error with `SELECT...` and no, the core tables use `wp_` as the prefix.

Comment: My suggestion is as @doublesharp look at users and permissions, and if not then create the table again but using the wpdb class... odd one

Comment: you have a prefix for the wp tables and wp is automatically assigning that to the tables

Comment: @doublesharp I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you talking about the PHP user? I create the table using phpMyAdmin, so I *think* the answer is yes. And the custom table is in the same db (sow2) as the rest of the WP core tables.

Comment: @rsz it won't do that unless you use `$wpdb->prefix`

Comment: You have a syntax error on the question. Is this is in the code too?

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse What's the error?

Comment: You double-close the `";` Hence why the colour-coding is messed up. If it's on the file I'm surprised it even runs.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Just a copy/paste typo. Not in the source code. (fixed above)

Comment: I was just reading this peace of text he inserted:
`WordPress database error: [Table 'sow2.spd_invites' doesn't exist]
INSERT INTO spd_invites (sender_id,receiver_id,job_id,job_title,job_slug,employer_id) VALUES ('799','809','6','Professional Basket Weaver','professional-basket-weaver','5')`

Comment: @Emerson - I just updated my answer with a function that will print out all the tables visible to the WP user, verified it works on a local site on my computer.

Comment: @doublesharp That was COOL! I ran it and `sdp_invites` is listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you haven't granted permission to you Wordpress MySQL database user for your new custom table, presumably because you created it with a different MySQL user through `phpMyAdmin`. Try running:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sow2.spd_invites TO 'wordpress_user'@'wordpress_host';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; -- load new privileges
```

Replace "wordpress_user" with your Wordpress MySQL username (can be found in `wp-config.php`) and "wordpress_host" with the hostname of your Wordpress server (or localhost if it's on the same server).

Keep in mind that this will allow the Wordpress MySQL full permissions (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DROP`, etc) to this table, which may not be desirable. See the MySQL docs for my info on the `GRANT` command - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

You will want to run your insert using the `query()` function as it won't return any results:

```
$wpdb->query($query);
```

To view all tables visible to your Wordpress MySQL user, add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file to print out the table names at the bottom of every page:

```
function show_all_tables(){
    global $wpdb; 
    foreach($wpdb->get_results("SHOW TABLES", ARRAY_N) as $table): 
        echo $table[0]."<br/>"; 
    endforeach;
} 
add_action('wp_footer', 'show_all_tables');
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to figure out what 'wordpress_user'@'wordpress_host' should be for my specific instance?

Comment: or since you have phpmyadmin access there is a tab called privilegdes, all users are listed there

Comment: Tried it. SQL query was successful. But when I reload the page I get the same error.

Comment: @MrD Good point, with the schema selected you can choose the privileges tab, and then edit the privileges from there - this is a good way to make sure you edit same user@host that you're using for login

Comment: I double checked that also, and all privileges are granted to the wp user.

Comment: @Emerson - try going the `phpMyAdmin` route, it might make it a bit easier to see what's going on if you aren't familiar with MySQL commands.

Comment: run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` to load the new privileges.

Comment: @doublesharp Ran that query also. No change. I added the phpMyAdmin privileges to the question.

Comment: @Emerson to me that says you don't have `INSERT` privileges on the new table for some reason.

Comment: @doublesharp I just deleted that comment because NOW all of a sudden I'm again seeing the error for the SELECT query also. I'm not sure if it was working or I made a mistake. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Emerson can you see the table when you run the function that calls `SHOW TABLES`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18824/discussion-between-doublesharp-and-emerson)

Comment: Yup. It lists my entire DB and `sdp_invites` is included. I've been reloading the page again and again and it looks like I'm not crazy: the error does appear INCONSISTENTLY when I test using the SELECT command. I copied the code into another template file and I get an error on one but nothing on the other. Really confusing.