# Interacting with Custom Database Tables in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a custom wordpress table(my_table). And i am inserting,updating all that good stuff to it. When i try to use

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->my_table",ARRAY_A);
```

or

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM my_table",ARRAY_A);
```

I get this error

```
WordPress database error: [Table 'mydatabase.my_table' doesn't exist]
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

I have tried to add my_table to wp-db.php as well but i still receive this error.

1. Yes the table is in the database
2. There is data in the table

Is their a config option of i need to change or somewhere else where i need to add my table name? I cannot find it for some reason.

**full error**

```
WordPress database error Table 'mydatabase.mytable' doesn't exist for query SELECT * FROM mytable made by do_action, call_user_func_array, promos
```

Comment: Does WordPress have permission to read that table?

Comment: @Catcall i created the table with the same user that i set for wordpress to use.

Comment: If mydatabase is WordPress database (to be confirmed by tiggles), then yes, it has permission. It can even create or delete any table in the database.

Comment: @barakadam It is in the wordpress database

Comment: And did you try, for example, `SELECT * FROM wp_options` so you can see if the other WordPress tables are found?

Comment: @barakadam yes i get results from wp_options and the other core tables that wordpress created on install

Comment: Man, I wish I could sit beside you and look at the same screen. Your problem is really starting to intrigue me.

Comment: Your last message was "my_table", now it's "mytable"...

Comment: @barakadam sorry it was a typo. I forgot wheither i put mytable or mytable while trying to not give away what i was working on. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147525/wordpress-custom-database-table-not-recognized And i ran his show_all_tables and my tables do not show up. I created the table with the same user as my wordpress user. I will report back soon. Probably the flushing of privs

Comment: @barakadam I tried everything that post above and it still doesn't work. I am at a lose for what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok tiggles, here is what I would do in your situation if you are still stuck. Create a new table, but this  time, by executing a SQL command from WordPress, using something like :

```
$wpdb->query('CREATE TABLE mynewtable (First_Name char(50), Last_Name char(50), ... etc.)');
```

Immediately check that you can query it. If so, then go to your databse and dump all data from `mytable` into this newly created table. Use this one instead.

If it was a user permission because the user that created the previous table was not the same as the one granted access to as WordPress, then you will be safe.

Comment: Yes create a table through wordpress worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your table `my_table` is, indeed, in the `mydatabase` database and if `mydatabase` is, indeed, WordPress' database, there is no reason why it should not work. If `mydatabase` is not WordPress database or if `my_table` is in another database, then it is normal that it does not work.